# AngularJS window.open in expression

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-repeat with posts. Each item has a facebook share button. I am currently binding the ng-click to controller action that uses window.open() (also tried with $window, same result). Seems to be working but, I am getting the following  [error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24parse%3aisecwindow?p0=sharePost%28post). How do I make this work properly?

Comment: Can you post a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) containing a boiled down version of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in CoffeeScript's implicit return. The function that was called by the expression had a last statement `window.open()` and value of that was probably a window object.